# Finite groups in which all proper subgroups are cyclic

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Is there any classification of finite group in which all proper subgroups are cyclic?

Would you please tell me a reference?

Comment: In addition to the cyclic groups themselves, you would be looking at the (finite) minimal non-cyclic groups. Geoff Robinson gives an answer at 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934131/classification-of-finite-minimal-non-cyclic-group
They are: $Q_8$, $C_p\times C_p$, and the unique group of order $pq^n$ with $p\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ with a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup and cyclic groups of order $pq^{n-1}$ and $q^n$.

Comment: The finite groups those abelian subgroups are cyclic have been classified by Zassenhaus and Suzuki (these are exactly the finite groups with periodic integral cohomology). There are exactly 6 types. A list can be found in Adem, Milgram: Cohomology of finite Groups, Theorem 6.15. Then you can check which of them have all their (proper) subgroups cyclic.

Answer (score 16):

All subgroups of a cyclic group (including the proper ones) are cyclic. And there is the following classification of non-cyclic finite groups, such that all their proper subgroups are cyclic:

> A finite group $G$ is a minimal noncyclic group if and only if $G$ is one of the following groups:
>
> 1) $C_p × C_p$, where $p$ is a prime
>
> 2) $Q_8$
>
> 3) $\langle a,b | a^p = b^{q^m} = 1, b^{−1}ab = a^{r}\rangle$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes and $r ≡ 1 \pmod q$, $r^q ≡1 \pmod p$.

This theorem first appeared in "[Non-abelian groups in which every subgroup is abelian](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1903-1500650-9)" by G.A.Miller and H.G.Moreno (1903)

Comment: Isn't this what @ArturoMagidin [said](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253777/finite-groups-in-which-all-proper-subgroups-are-cyclic#comment624713_253777)?

Comment: @LSp Arturo didn't give the Miller, Moreno reference.